# Tensor algebra problem from the derivation of covariant derivative

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, tensors

I was reading a way of deriving the covariant derivative (using (1,1)-tensor) and found it hard to understand one specific operation.
$${\frac{\partial a^{k}_{m}}{\partial y^{p}}=\frac{\partial a^{k}_{m}}{\partial x^{q}}\frac{\partial x^{q}}{\partial y^{p}}=\frac{\partial a^{k}_{m}}{\partial x^{q}}S^{q}_{p}=(S^{k}_{i}A^{i}_{j}T^{j}_{m})_{,p}}$$where ${S}$ and ${T}$ are transformation matrices, ${A}$ is tensor expressed by curvilinear coordinates and ${a}$ is tensor expressed in noncurvilinear coordinates. After taking the normal partial derivative and substituting with some expressions of ${T}$, ${S}$ and ${\Gamma}$, they find that:
$${\frac{\partial a^{k}_{m}}{\partial x^{q}}S^{q}_{p}=S^{k}_{h}\Gamma^{h}_{ip}A^{i}_{j}T^{j}_{m}+S^{k}_{i}A^{i}_{j,p}T^{j}_{m}-S^{k}_{i}A^{i}_{j}\Gamma^{j}_{hp}T^{h}_{m}\space(1)}$$
$${T^{i}_{k}a^{k}_{m;q}S^{m}_{j}S^{q}_{p}=\Gamma^{i}_{hp}A^{h}_{j}+A^{i}_{j,p}-A^{i}_{h}\Gamma^{h}_{jp}\space(2)}$$
How do they make the transition from 1 to 2 if it is possible to be shown more explicitly?

Comment: The left-hand side of (2) is the same one of (1) multiplied by $T^i_{\phantom{k}k}$ from the left and by $S^m_{\phantom{j}j}$ from the right. How do both contract which any of the terms in the right-hand side of (1)?

Comment: One observation: as the metric is not necessarily flat, you should be making a clear distinction on which index goes further to the left/right of which. Ex.: $S^q_p$ is ambiguous, which of the two indexes is the covariant one, the **first** of the **second**? That is, is it $S^q_{\phantom{p}p}$ (S^q_{\phantom{p}p}) or $S^{\phantom{q}q}_p$ (S_{\phantom{q}q}_p)?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. The paper I read takes as default first to be contravariant indices that's why I missed to point it.

Comment: I see the sides are multiplied but don't know how do they simplify them.

Comment: You need to check the definitions of $S$ and $T$. Notice *if the were inverse of each other* multiplying by them as I mentioned would yield the expected result.

Comment: Yeah they are inverse of each other, the only problem are the results' indices, I cannot come up with the correct answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29228/discussion-between-user1163511-and-masl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $T$ and $S$ are inverse of each other, it is $T^i_{\phantom{k}k}S^k_{\phantom{h}h}=\delta^i_{\phantom{h}h}$.

Let's write the right-hand side of (1) such we clearly distinguish the bounded indices ($h,i,j$)from the free ones in both, (1), ($k,m,p$), and (2), ($i,j,p$).

$$S^k_a\Gamma^a_{bp} A^b_cT^c_m\,+\,S^k_aA^a_{b,p}T^b_m\,+\,S^k_aA^a_b\Gamma^b_{cp} T^c_m$$
Multiplying by $T^i_k$ on the left and $S^m_j$ on the right we have
$$\delta^i_a\Gamma^a_{bp} A^b_c\delta^c_j\,+\,\delta^i_aA^a_{b,p}\delta^b_j\,+\,\delta^i_aA^a_b\Gamma^b_{cp}\delta^c_j\,=\\
\Gamma^i_{bp} A^b_j\,+\,A^i_{j,p}\,+\,A^i_b\Gamma^b_{jp}\quad(2)
$$
as wanted.

Note: The take-home lesson is: bounded or *contracted indices* can be renamed anytime without changing a tensor.